# "Segments" option missing in Cinema 4D when adding subdivision surface modifier

Tags: cinema4d

I'm having a very annoying problem with Cinema 4D. I was following a tutorial step-by-step, and I was only four minutes in when I ran into a problem. The person in the video added a subdivision surface modifier then demonstrated how to change the number of segments on the Y-value of the object, but when I go to the object properties panel, I have no option to change the number of segments. I also noticed that mine is a polygon object while his is a cube, and I don't know what I did wrong or how to change it back.

[image]

Comment: Apart from the fact that it is very difficult to unpick somebody else's tutorial, it's almost impossible for anybody to know where you went wrong without access to the tutorial. Also, 3D modelling software is not a great fit for this site. There's a Blender Stack Exchange (no Cinema 4D SE yet), but probably not much use to you. Maybe reach out to a Cinema 4D community instead.